# Joining sql views in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view, union-all

How can I join views using sql? I'm using Oracle at the moment?

Sql view 1

```
CREATE VIEW florence_staff AS
SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE libname ='florence'
```

Sql view 2

```
CREATE VIEW alexandria_staff AS
SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE libname ='alexandria'
```

I'm doing this to check if the fragmentation is correct, if you get what i mean. Thanks :))

Comment: Do you want a `UNION` (which will list both views in sequence) or a `JOIN`, which relates the two tables on one or more fields?

Comment: yeh a union actually sorry :)), im so stupid

Comment: Does that mean you have answered your own question? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These will be distinct result sets as the `libname` is different so use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM florence_staff
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM alexandria_staff
```